# SQL Server. Get Zeros in inner joins with sum

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
PRODUCTS(product_id, name, price)
(1,'Apple', $10)
(2,'Cherry', $20)
(3,'Watermelon', $30)
```

And this:

```
STOCK(product_id, number)
(1,5)
(1,3)
(2,5)
```

With this:

```
SELECT
  PRODUCTS.product_id,
  SUM(STOCK.number),
FROM
  STOCK
  INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON PRODUCTS.product_id = STOCK.product_id
GROUP BY
  PRODUCTS.product_id
```

I can get this:

```
(Apple, 8)
(Cherry, 5)
```

But I want to get this:

```
(Apple, 8)
(Cherry, 5)
(Watermelon, 0)
```

This can be done in MySQL with a RIGHT JOIN, but in SQL Server not, any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I dont see codbar in your table

Comment: I think you're not showing us your correct query.  RIGHT JOIN in SQL Server works the same as in MySQL.  This should work.   Can you create a reproducible script, or SQLFiddle?   Why do you mention "inner joins" in the question's title?

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak english very well. I had a different query in my database and the "translation" was a bit wrong hehehehe

Comment: Use a RIGHT JOIN, like you had in your MySQL query and it should give the desired results.  Of course an INNER JOIN will not include Products that are not also in Stock.  Your statement,  "..but in SQL Server not," is not true.

Comment: @TabAlleman INNER, LEFT and RIGHT gives the same result.

Comment: I am pretty sure they do not.   Can you create a reproducible script?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. In my actual DB, I create the example again. I think (not sure) that the problem is that I was putting the FROM [Table1] LEFT JOIN [Table2] in a different order ([Table2] LEFT JOIN [Table1]) . Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  PRODUCTS.product_id,
  COALESCE(SUM(STOCK.number), 0)
FROM
  PRODUCTS
  LEFT JOIN STOCK ON PRODUCTS.product_id = STOCK.product_id
GROUP BY
  PRODUCTS.product_id
```

**Note:** `RIGHT JOIN` is also available in SQL Server and the syntax is the same as in MySQL.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2948/5)

Comment: Why would this produce different results from his current RIGHT JOIN?

Comment: @TabAlleman It wouldn't, it's just simpler and more intuitive this way (I think).

Comment: @LuisEduardoSP Why is that?

Comment: If you alter this from LEFT to RIGHT, it DOES change the results.

Comment: You also want to` sum(isnull(stock.number,0))` to not get a null value.

Comment: I think the real question is why doesn't the RIGHT JOIN in the question work, and exploring the left join equivalent will not lead to an answer to that question.

Comment: @JiggsJedi Nope, it doesn't change the results. In my actual query, doesn't work the SUM(ISNULL())

Comment: @LuisEduardoSP There seems to be a problem with your actual scenario not yet described in the OP. The fiddle demo I've added to my answer demonstrates that my query produces the required result set. If there is an issue with this query then please edit your question.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` as follows, and use `ISNULL()` to SUM a 0 where no stock exists.

```
DECLARE @PRODUCTSTABLE TABLE (product_id INT, name VARCHAR(10), price MONEY)
DECLARE @STOCK TABLE (product_id INT, number INT)
INSERT INTO @PRODUCTSTABLE
VALUES
(1,'Apple', 10),
(2,'Cherry', 20),
(3,'Watermelon', 30)

INSERT INTO @STOCK
VALUES
(1,5),
(1,3),
(2,5)

SELECT P.name, SUM(ISNULL(S.number,0))
FROM @PRODUCTSTABLE P
LEFT JOIN @STOCK S ON P.product_id=S.product_id
GROUP BY P.name
```

Comment: I'm un-deleting my answer as the other contains too many errors.

Comment: Thanks, this is the example I need.